# Detecting Ctrl + click button and click button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For the button, how to detect whether it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click a button, in the click event handler?
I am using VS 2010 using C#.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: @Robuust - it's actually impossible to say if this is an exact duplicate since the code for WinForms and WPF are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are we talking about winforms, wpf or asp application? I will make a quick assumption that it's winforms, so here goes:

```
Form Form1;
button.Click += click;

private void click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Form1.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    ... // Whatever you need here
}
```